# Get value from PropertyInfo without object

Tags: c#, reflection

I am using reflection to get all my modifier types from the assembly and I put them in a dictionary.

I want to see what content a modifier takes. Each NodeContent has interfaces to match them to the modifier. Each modifier has an abstract property GetContentType which returns an interface type to show what content it can take.

But it forces me to create an object of the type to use PropertyInfo.GetValue(), which defies what I am trying to do because I don't know what content type it takes.

I assume I could just get the first constructor and the first parameter but that to me doesn't feel very safe.

So my question is. Is there another way to get PropertyInfo.GetValue() without using an object but just a type?

```
public static Dictionary<string, Type> GetFittingModifiers(NodeContent content)
{
    Dictionary<string, Type> fits = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string,Type> modifierType in modifiers)
    {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = modifierType.Value.GetProperty("GetContentType");
        Modifier modifier = //make object of modifierType.Value without knowing what the constructor takes
        Type contentType = (Type)propertyInfo.GetValue(modifier, null);
        if (HasInterface(content, contentType))
            fits.Add(modifierType.Key, modifierType.Value);
    }
    return fits;
}
```

Comment: `PropertyInfo.GetValue` retrieves the *value* of the property, which obviously requires an object (in the case of a non-static property). You seem to want `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`. (I think, the question's not entirely clear to me.) Of course this only gets the static (declared) type of the property; getting the *runtime* type of the property value is, again, impossible without actually creating an object (or pseudo-interpreting the code through reflection, but that could lead you down very dark paths).

Comment: I edited the question for more clarity. I want to get the value. The value indicates what type of content that modifier takes.

Comment: _"Is there another way to get PropertyInfo.GetValue() without using a object but just a type?"_ - no, because it's an instance property, you need an instance. Please create a [mcve]. You might have to reconsider the design altogether.

Comment: Then yeah, reflecting over the constructor (and enforcing it takes only one parameter that is the type you're after) looks like the only way, and that's ugly. Consider exposing the type through an attribute instead `[ContentType(...)]` -- those are *designed* to be easy to inspect with reflection. Alternatively, make the property `static` and have one modifier type deal with only one content type, for all instances. (But even then an attribute would probably be cleaner.)

Comment: Yes Jeroen Mostert, I think that is the answer that I am looking for!

Comment: @JeroenMostert could you post it as an answer then I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in any clean way.

To get the value of an instance property, you need to call the accessor method. That method takes `this` as an argument. Even if it doesn't strictly *require* it, the argument is there. Additionally, to have this work at all, the property must be virtual, which again means you need an instance of the specific type to invoke the right method. You can fake this, but it just sounds like your design is just bad and now you need to find a quick fix.

The simplest way to associate type information with any kind of value is through attributes. So instead of using a `GetContentType` virtual property, you'll define a `ContentTypeAttribute`, and then apply it to the target type:

```
[ContentType(typeof(SomePlug))]
public class SomeModifier { ... }
```

Attributes apply to the type, not an instance of a type, so you can query them easily:

```
var contentType = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(modifier, typeof(ContentTypeAttribute));
```